# Combine every combination of two dataframes without matching columns

Tags: r

I have two dataframes that I want to combine, for each possible combination.

Basically, I dataframes like this:

```
> table1 = data.frame(a1 = c("a","b"), a2 = c("c", "d"))
> table1
  a1 a2
1  a  c
2  b  d
> table2 = data.frame(b1 = c("e", "f"), b2 = c("g", "h"))
> table2
  b1 b2
1  e  g
2  f  h
```

and I want to get a result like this:

```
> combinedtable = data.frame(a1 = c("a","a", "b","b"), a2 = c("c", "c", "d", "d"), b1 = c("e", "f","e", "f"), b2 = c("g", "h","g", "h"))
> combinedtable
  a1 a2 b1 b2
1  a  c  e  g
2  a  c  f  h
3  b  d  e  g
4  b  d  f  h
```

Is there a neat way to do this? What I eventually want to do is to run an lapply on the resulting table. Otherwise I need to write a function like:

for each row in X, apply this function for each row in Y.

Combining first seems more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### base R

```r
with(expand.grid(a=seq_len(nrow(table1)), b=seq_len(nrow(table2))), 
     cbind(table1[a,], table2[b,]))
#     a1 a2 b1 b2
# 1    a  c  e  g
# 2    b  d  e  g
# 1.1  a  c  f  h
# 2.1  b  d  f  h
```

or

```r
merge(table1, table2, by = NULL)
#   a1 a2 b1 b2
# 1  a  c  e  g
# 2  b  d  e  g
# 3  a  c  f  h
# 4  b  d  f  h
```

### dplyr

Similar to the `by=NULL` method, we can do

```r
dplyr::full_join(table1, table2, by = character())
```

Comment: Merge by NULL is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach with `purrr`:

```
purrr::pmap_dfr(table1, ~ data.frame(..., table2))
```

Returning:

```
  a1 a2 b1 b2
1  a  c  e  g
2  a  c  f  h
3  b  d  e  g
4  b  d  f  h
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have it for each combination of `a1` and `a2`. I read this question a little differently so just in case: if you want a table with every combination of all levels of all columns:

```
cbind(table1, table2) %>% 
  complete(a1, a2, nesting(b1, b2))
```